# Using RegEx within Yii 2's UrlManager rulesets

Tags: php, regex, yii, yii2

I'm trying to use `Yii 2's` `UrlManager` to set a rule and I know you can use Regex within parameters you wanna pass such as:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'foo/<id:\d+>/?' => 'foo/view',
    ],
],
```

The above works fine, even the optional `/` on the end because of the `?`.

However, I'm wondering what if I want to use RegEx somewhere else in the rule, however I don't need it passed as a param..... such as.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'foo/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)\.<id:\d+>/?' => 'foo/view',
    ],
],
```

The above doesn't work. Basically I want to support URL's such as:

```
foo/some-name-123-end.99/
foo/some-name-123-end.99
```

Then the `99` (which can be any number) will be passed as the `id` variable.

...or is there something wrong with my RegEx?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#named-parameters) you can only specify regular expressions for parameters. Example:

```
'foo/<tmpParam:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>.<id:\d+>/?' => 'foo/view',
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I ended up doing it. Oh well.